# Как передавать данные по RS485 использую драйвер 8250?

Tags: linux, uart

Нужно передавать данные ModbusRTU по RS485, в котором надо переключать RTS, чтобы данные можно было отправить или принимать. В интернете нашел, что это можно делать с помощью драйвера 8250, который сам в нужное время будет переключать RTS, но как его использовать включить,применить для целей не могу понять, можете объяснить как это делать?

Comment: hardware flow control должен быть CTS/RTS

Comment: @PavelGridin, вы путаете с rs232. Эмуляция RS485 определяет направление данных с помощью сигнала RTS. По сути он используется как GPIO.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/amarburg/07564916d8d32e20e6ae375c1c83a995 (Сам не проверял, но мысль там правильная)

Comment: Ещё вариант http://www.glomationinc.com/Support/9X25/rs485test.c

Comment: Я не совсем понял, как указать, а главное, где указывается GPIO, которым я делаю переключение? Иначе если запускаю без изменений то авто переключений нет приходится

Comment: Есть два момента первый мне нужно реализовать передачу данных после того, как они пришли и обратно, и второе разве для этого надо использовать драйвер, а не библиотеку serial. Можете растолковать.

Comment: RTS — это физический провод из чипа 8250 на разъём RS232. Он всегда есть на портах с поддержкой аппаратного контроля потока.